# From the word SHOWERDOWN, how many 4-letter words begin and end with a vowel?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations, combinations

I had this question from my Probability worksheet:

From the word SHOWERDOWN, how many 4-letter words begin and end with a vowel (i.e. O, E, or O)?

I did:
**Case 1**: 2W's = 1
**Case 2**: All distinct letters = 6P2 = 30

I then multiplied 30+1 by $\frac{3P2}{2!}$, because I need to also arrange the vowels and divide out the repetition of 'O'.

However, I am unsure if my answer (i.e. 93) is correct, so any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing cases - for example, what about cases where all three vowels are present? Two of them are at two ends and one of them is one of the two middle  letters.

Once you choose two vowels, you are left with $7$ distinct letters:
`S H W R D N E` or `S H W R D N O`

There are $ \displaystyle {7 \choose 2}$ ways to choose two letters and $2$ ways to arrange them. Also there are $3$ way to place two vowels:
`O _ _ O`, `E _ _ O`, `O _ _ E`

That leads to $~\displaystyle 3 \cdot 2 \cdot {7 \choose 2} = 126$ four letter words, not including words with two W's. There are $3$ four letter words with two W's.

So, the answer should be $129$.

Answer (score 2):

- there are $3$ possibilities for start/end, viz $\;O...E,\; E...O,\; O...O$
- two from the $7$ distinct letters left can be inserted in $7*6+1^@ = 43$ ways
- Multiply the two

[$+1^@$ takes care of the case when both the middle letters are $Ws$]

Comment: @Math Lover: Thanks, good catch ! (+1)

Comment: sure no problem :)